# Make synchronous code asynchronous in Python asyncio/aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

Still learning Web scraping and trying to wrap my head around Python's asyncio/aiohttp libraries.I have a fully functional sequential code which works fine in synchronous environment and when I try to implement it to asyncio that's where the trouble starts I've gone through a lot of articles about asyncio but couldn't figure out the solution for my case.

Here is sequential working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


cookies = {
    'b': '1.2qu49mazdxsj0.40fc8b88.quqq3d.9q7z',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Spoonflower-Window-UUID': 'a9bc37a2-9eb2-4a1e-8ea1-fcee89347364',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.spoonflower.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.spoonflower.com/',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'If-None-Match': 'W/95d6572c326b81ce98c7ae27ac449d42',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

res = requests.get('https://www.spoonflower.com/spoonflower_fabrics')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
fabrics = [fabric.find('h2').text.strip() for fabric in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product_detail medium_text'})]
fabric = [("_".join(fab.upper().replace(u"\u2122", '').split())) for fab in fabrics]
for index in range(len(fabric)):
    if 'COTTON_LAWN_(BETA)' in fabric[index]:
        fabric[index] = 'COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL'
    elif 'COTTON_POPLIN' in fabric[index]:
        fabric[index] = 'COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA'
    elif 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT' in fabric[index]:
        fabric[index] = 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA'
    elif 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUÉ' in fabric[index]:
        fabric[index] = 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUE'
    elif 'CYPRESS_COTTON' in fabric[index]:
        fabric[index] = 'CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA'
#print(fabric)
#print(fabric)
#https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en
#https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id=6444170&page_locale=en

item_endpoint = 'https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en'
item_response = requests.get(item_endpoint).json()

items_dict = OrderedDict()
for item in item_response['page_results']:
    for fab_type in fabric[0:-3]:
        #print(type(fab_type))
        details_endpoint = 'https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_'+ fab_type +'?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='+str(item['designId'])+'&page_locale=en'
        #print(details_endpoint)
        details_endpoint_response = requests.get(details_endpoint, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()
        designName = item['name']
        screenName = item['user']['screenName']
        fabric_name = details_endpoint_response['data']['fabric_code']
        try:
            test_swatch_meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['TEST_SWATCH_METER']['price']
        except:
            test_swatch_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            fat_quarter_meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['FAT_QUARTER_METER']['price']
        except:
            fat_quarter_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['METER']['price']
        except:
            meter = 'N/A'
        
        if (designName, screenName) not in items_dict.keys():
            items_dict[(designName, screenName)] = {}

        itemCount = len(items_dict[(designName, screenName)].values()) / 4
        items_dict[(designName, screenName)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fabric_name,
        'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
        'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
        'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})
            
        

        print(designName, screenName, fabric_name, test_swatch_meter,fat_quarter_meter, meter)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(items_dict, orient='index').reset_index(drop=False)
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0':'designName','level_1':'screenName'})
df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)
```

And here is my asyncio try:

```
    import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

from requests.sessions import session


item_endpoint = 'https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en'

def get_fabric_names():
    res = requests.get('https://www.spoonflower.com/spoonflower_fabrics')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    fabrics = [fabric.find('h2').text.strip() for fabric in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product_detail medium_text'})]
    fabric = [("_".join(fab.upper().replace(u"\u2122", '').split())) for fab in fabrics]
    for index in range(len(fabric)):
        if 'COTTON_LAWN_(BETA)' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL'
        elif 'COTTON_POPLIN' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA'
        elif 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA'
        elif 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUÉ' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUE'
        elif 'CYPRESS_COTTON' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA'
    return fabric

async def fetch_design_endpoint(session, design_url):
    async with session.get(design_url) as response:
        extracting_endpoint = await response.text()
        _json_object = json.loads(extracting_endpoint)
        return _json_object['page_results']

async def fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_endpoint):
    async with session.get(pricing_endpoint) as response:
        data_endpoint = await response.text()
        _json_object = json.loads(data_endpoint)
        items_dict = OrderedDict()
        # for item in fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint):
        #     designName = item['name']
        #     screenName = item['user']['screenName']
        fabric_name = _json_object['data']['fabric_code']
        try:
            test_swatch_meter = _json_object['data']['pricing']['TEST_SWATCH_METER']['price']
        except:
            test_swatch_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            fat_quarter_meter = _json_object['data']['pricing']['FAT_QUARTER_METER']['price']
        except:
            fat_quarter_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            meter = _json_object['data']['pricing']['METER']['price']
        except:
            meter = 'N/A'

        print(fabric_name, test_swatch_meter,fat_quarter_meter, meter)

        if (designName, screenName) not in items_dict.keys():
            items_dict[(designName, screenName)] = {}

        itemCount = len(items_dict[(designName, screenName)].values()) / 4
        return items_dict[(designName, screenName)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fabric_name,
        'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
        'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
        'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})

async def main():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fabric_type = get_fabric_names()
        design_page = await fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint)
        for item in design_page:
            for fab_type in fabric_type[0:-3]:
                pricing_url = 'https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_'+fab_type+'?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='+str(item['designId'])+'&page_locale=en'
                await fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_url)

                tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(
                    fetch_pricing_data(session, pricing_url)

                    )
                )

        content = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return content
results = asyncio.run(main())
```

ERRORS:

```
    File "async_web_scraper.py", line 62, in fetch_pricing_data
       if (designName, screenName) not in items_dict.keys():
    NameError: name 'designName' is not defined
```

I want some hints on properly implementing asyncio.Any help is much appreciated. All of the tutorials I've come across online seem to be a tad over my head.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you want this code to be async? There's nothing to run i parallell from what I see.

Comment: @JohanSchiff 2 Reasons: 1) It is taking too much time when getting price data for different fabric types there are total 24 fabric types for each design and 84 designs on each page so I thought it would be nice to speed up a little bit. 2) To grasp the concepts of asyncio/aiohttp better.

Comment: Ok. Got ya. Parallell coming up later, I suppose. I think your main problem is that you're `await`ing non-async functions. You don't need everything to be async. So, for example the `response.text()` call cannot be awaited, because it's not async. Also, `soup_d(html)` function has no reason to be `async`, since it's not `await`ing anything.

The point of async is that some functions can run in background (mainly IO) and return control to the event loop, to be resumed at a later time. If a function has no code that will return control to event loop, it does not need async.

Comment: Sorry, see not that I was wrong about `response.text()`.

Comment: Yeah it make sense extracting the names of all the fabric doesn't need to be async at all i guess because it's just getting the names from a single page.Am I right?

Comment: To my understanding, no. If it does not `await`, it does not need to be async.

Comment: @dougj          code  need lot works. First you have to understand that without `await` in  `async` function  will not work in run . you have to `await` response , most of your code you are using direct response , second you have to proper use to `create_task` and `asyncio.gather` . small suggestion `try/except` can be done in one block no need to repeat it. i would advise let one function  do one work like divide  fetching data , then extract design and endpoint function like this.

Comment: @gaurav I updated the code may be now it makes sense.It would be more helpful if you can show some code example through my code so i can understand it better if you don't mind.

Comment: @dougj          present error is you have commented `designName` so it is not define to i will suggest you to remove from comment . second `fetch_design_endpoint` also a async function so that should be `await` then use in for loop.

Comment: @gaurav This is where i am struggling designName and designID both are coimg from fetch_design_endpoint and I can't figure out how to get those values in fetch_pricing_data so it return the OrderedDict as i am expecting.

Comment: design_page = await fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint) it's been await

Comment: @dougj          I am taking around 42/43 line where you are using  direct in for loop now it is commented you have to `await` that to use in for loop so you can not get `designName` not defined error  like this `new_var = await fetch_design_endpoint(session, item_endpoint)  for item in new_var:  designName = item['name'] screenName = item['user']['screenName']`

Comment: Got it!It's working now

Comment: @gaurav Can you tell me what is this error means: ```TypeError: 'URL' object is not iterable```

Comment: @dougj         it simply mean you using for or while loop  for a object which is not iiterable . see `URL`  variable  where on line error showing . updated the code so we can help.

Comment: @gaurav Thanks for getting back to me.Actually I was having some difficulties with yarl.URL object which is giving that error now it's fixed.But on the other hand I'm facing difficulties because I updated a code little bit so, should I upload another post or update the current question with updated code?

Comment: @dougj          ask another question so it will be in new tag and more people can help.